# Query fails randomly whilst inserting with PHP mcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, mcrypt

Banging my head against a wall here. But I am using `utf8_general_ci` encoding and the type is `tinyblob` in a `MySQL DB`

I use `Mcrypt` on rows uname, pwrod and email as seen in the insert. Sometimes this will insert, others it won't. This obviously depends on the string used to generate the encryption.

This is my insert

```
INSERT INTO `users` ( `uname` , `pword` , `email` , `gender` , `provider` , `level` , `dob` , `confirmed` , `regdate` , `confirmationCode`, `ip` ) 
VALUES ('“­É.¡Ec', '$2a$15$3G.7Pfap0dfWnEZxVPKWjewcLUA6tYm7a1al6I0QNZUCNcdl6E6Mu', 'ðÖŒÅÕ'Ý£mY]ª±¼ ôn´}Ð>d¢', '0','manual', '0', '2014-02-16', '0',NOW(), 'f5ab855e95eab47948b05cfe5a03e4d6', '127.0.0.1' ); 
Error Nr: 1064 Error Msg: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Ý£mY]??? ?n?}?>d?', '0','manual', '0', '2014-02-16', '0',NOW(), 'f5ab855e95eab' at line 14
```

If I change the `'` to `` ` `` then I get the following error:

```
 Error Nr: 1300 Error Msg: Invalid utf8 character string: '\x93\xAD\xC9.\xA1E\x04c'
```

I assume I need to change my `char encoding`? But this is where my knowledge falls down (and just in general all encodings :) )

Comment: do you really need to encrypt any of that.

Comment: Sadly I do :( The data I'm working with needs to be completely discreet! Bad times, but nesesery.

Comment: if i stole your db, would i maybe have the encryption key also, ? where is it stored?

Comment: Luckily the DB is on a different server from my php :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability:

```
  [..snip..], 'ðÖŒÅÕ'Ý£mY]ª±¼ ôn´}Ð>d¢',[..snip..]
              ^--start string
                    ^---end string
```

You are building your query incorrectly - either by NOT escaping the data you're stuff into the query string, or not using your DB library's prepared statements/placeholders functionality.

Comment: Good and actually quite obvious spot, thanks. I'll just give hat a quick whirl right there. Poor boby tables! A question if I may Marc is, if I escape the `'` won't this mean that I'll have to remove them when decrypting?

Comment: Any ideas on the escpaing string question marc/

Comment: Sorry marc, but it seems that I'm still having problems. I did believe I had fixed it. So I am escaping. As for the prepared statements, I admit I have no idea what these are. Other then googling any pointers?